# Azure Devops Release Pipelines - Variable to obtain the Source (build pipeline) value?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

I am looking at a way of extracting out the name of "Source (build pipeline)" value in a Release from a build artifact screen.

In the [attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvRfa.png) the "Source (build pipeline)" value (in red circle) is "Subscriber-Build", whereas the Source Alias always has the _ underscore character, e.g. "_SubscriberBuild"

I've tried the following variable and variations of:

```
$(Release.Artifacts.{$(Release.PrimaryArtifactSourceName)}.DefinitionName)
```

as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#artifact-variables) but with no success.

Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of **4c74356b41** it's correct, if it's your primary artifact you can use just `Build.DefinitionName`.

But, if you want to use the variable mentioned in the docs you can get the value in this way (in PowerShell):

```
$primaryAlias = $env:Release_PrimaryArtifactSourceAlias

$definitionVariable = "Release_Artifact_$($primaryAlias)_DefinitionName"

# Get the value of the environment variable Release.Artifact.{alias}.DefnitionName:

$primaryDefnitionName = (Get-Item env:$defnitionVariable).Value
```

In the above way you can get the build definition name although is not your primary artifact, just change the first line, for example: `triggerAlias = $env:Release_TriggeringArtifact_Alias` for triggered artifacts.

Comment: Thanks - that worked - by the way there is a typo in your answer - as I just cut-n-pasted it I found out. Its Build.DefinitionName

Comment: Thanks! I added the missing `i`.

Answer (score 1):

for the primary artifact you can just use `$(Build.DefinitionName)` to retrieve its build definition name as the document suggests